# How do I create pagination for image slideshow using foreach loop

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create dotted pagination for the image slideshow. I don't know how to set the

to loop through the number of the images in the array and when I tried to add it manually, it is rendered on a single image.

```
  echo '<div id="slider">';
                        echo '<div class="slides">';
                        echo '<div class="switch">
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <div class="on"></div>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>';
                            $slider_array = get_field('slider');
                            foreach($slider_array as $sub_array) {
                                    if (!empty($sub_array )) {
                                        echo '<div class="slider">';
                                        // echo '<div class="legend"></div>';
                                        echo '<div class="content">';
                                            echo '<div class="content-txt">';
                                            echo '<h2>'.$sub_array['slider_text'].'</h2>';  
                                            echo'</div>';
                                            echo '</div>';
                                            echo '<div class="images">';
                                            echo '<img src="'.$sub_array['slider_image'].'" />';
                                            echo'</div>';
                                        echo '</div>';

                                    }                   
                            }

                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';
```

**CSS for the pagination** 
I tried to isolate the css for the image slideshow as it is lengthy but the image slideshow is working perfectly as it loops through the array. I have just a problem to create a dotted pagination for the individual images in the show. Your help will be appreciated.

```
.switch{
  width:120px;
  height:10px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  z-index:99;
  left:30px;
}
.switch > ul{
  list-style:none;
}
.switch > ul > li{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#333;
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.switch ul{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.on{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#f39c12;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-animation:on 30s infinite;
  -moz-animation:on 30s infinite;
  animation:on 30s infinite;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but it sounds like there is only one image in $slider_array. If you run count($slider_array) what is the number of elements?

Also, if you are going to put PHP in the same file as HTML you can close the PHP tags using ?> and then reopen PHP using <?php - it's a bit nicer than echoing everywhere - that said it's even better to use a rendering engine like twig

Comment: I am sure you want something like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: @Coderrrr twig? Is it possible to use it with WordPress?

Comment: @hans-könig something like that but I don't want JS

Comment: I don't know if twig can be used with WP - did you have any luck getting the images to show?

Comment: Yes, I got that part and I cleaned up the code as well.